# How to pass and call the snowflake procedure with CLob data type

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

there is a requirement for me for storing a clob data type in SF table . I am using a stored procedure invocation to do the insert into table . As of now i am specifying variant as the input type instead of clob in procedure . Can some one please suggest how to pass clob data type and how to invoke a Snowflake procedure with clob data type input parameter.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: how can we pass a variant data into a stored procedure and call the same from snowflake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake doesn't support the CLOB datatype so you can't do what you want.

[Unsupported Datatypes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-unsupported.html)

Comment: i have checked that ,  i need to pass this  below json as an input parameter,.

Comment: {
 "employeeId": "351438",
 "userId": "nikhil",
 "sourceSystem": "myapp",
 "loginId": "nikhil",
 
}

Comment: so  how to invoke it so while creating the proc , should i use variant and while calling the app how to pass the json in prcoedure call

Comment: Why does your original question talk about CLOB datatypes and you are now talking about json/variants? Please can you edit your question (don’t add more comments) to clearly explain what you are trying to do and provide sample data - if you aren’t talking about CLOB data then you might want to close this  question and create a new one

Comment: Why i said about clob and now why i said about variant is because , while i am writing data into oracle we are using clob inside which we are storing the json  data. But while converting to snowflake , i was not sure how to replace clob . Hence after the research i thought to use variant.

Comment: Ok, but what you put in your original question is very different from what you have subsequently explained in various comments - hence my request that you go back and edit your question so that it reflects what you are actually trying to do (and all the information someone would need to help you is in one place), rather than requiring someone to read through your comments and try and work out what your question actually is

Comment: sure will keep that one  mind while posting further questions